Python to Cython -by keyword causes issues
Ive turned my python code to cython and it gets tons of errors from lines of code using the word -by

Here are the two cases: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
I get an error for the common.by- I get an error: Identifier expected

sorted_df = df.sort_values(by="dist", ascending = False)-Here i get an error also for the by.
Is there someway to override it or import and sort differently?

I don't believe Cython treats by as a keyword so as far as I can tell this should work. The question is pretty unclear though - e.g. is this an error when you compile it or run it? It really needs an [mre] to know exactly what you're doing.
